# How to plus or minus the css font size by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an user provided html saved in database "with or without" css font-size specified.

And try to make a button to enlarge or decrease the font-size on the doms but maintain the 
relative size.

I defined an variable def_size to be 16px and cur_size to be the base size on the fly.

But I dont know how to deal with the dom with size predefined?I tried the preg_replace,but it failed.

http://jsfiddle.net/95kDZ/

```
function change_font_size(csize){
var $cotent_html=$('.content');
cur_base=cur_base+csize;
//without style,just add the css to the whole div"
   $cotent_html.css('font-size',cur_base.toString()+'px');
/*
```

Please give me some hint.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to get every element that could contain text: `p`, `span`, `div`, etc and apply your `font-size` logic on it instead on the whole `html` root. You need to target specific `html` element in order to overwrite its style.

Updated working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/95kDZ/3/).

Code:

```
var def_size=16,
    cur_base=def_size;

$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    change_font_size(parseInt($(this).data('csize')));
});

function change_font_size(csize){
    var $cotent_html=$('.content');

    cur_base=cur_base+csize;
    //without style,just add the css to the whole div"
    $cotent_html.find('span, p, div').css('font-size', cur_base.toString()+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A foreach function would be better for this

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95kDZ/7/)

Code:

```
function change_font_size(csize){
    var $content_html=$('.content p, .content span');
    $content_html.each(function(){
        var cur_size = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
        cur_size += csize;
        console.log(cur_size);
        $(this).css('font-size', cur_size.toString()+'px');
    });

}
```